# Django: TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to add a template which displays a `ModelForm` on my Django app's home page. I made a separate app within my project for the home page called `home` since it isn't static, but the template I'm using is living in the main templates directory used by my project right now.

When I run my server and try to navigate to /home, I get the following error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/
{'form': <ActionCodeForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(action_code)>}
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8300/home/
Django Version: 1.9.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
{'form': <ActionCodeForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(action_code)>}
```

How do I fix this error? I have tried looking at other SO answers for TemplateDoesNotExist errors and saw that it has to do with the `'DIRS'` setting but mine seems to be set up correctly so I don't know what would be causing the error.

Here is the templates section of my `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Here's the template (`action_code_form.html`):

```
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ form }}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is home/views.py:

```
from home.forms import ActionCodeForm

def action_code_form(request):
    form = ActionCodeForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActionCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            action_code = form.cleaned_data['action_code']
            form.save()
    return render('action_code_form.html', {'form': form})
```

home/models.py:

```
class ActionCode(models.Model):
    action_code = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=10,
                                   verbose_name="Action Code")
```

home/forms.py:

```
from home.models import ActionCode

class ActionCodeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ActionCode
        fields = ('action_code',)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut incorrectly. The first argument should be the `request`.

```
return render(request, 'action_code_form.html', {'form': form})
```